# Translate English into first order logic: there are an infinite number of something

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

The Twin-Prime Conjecture: There are an infinite number of pairs of primes that differ by 2.

Translation:
$$\forall z \exists y (\text{Greater}(y,z)\wedge\text{Prime}(y)\wedge\text{Prime}(\text{sum}(y,2)))$$

Why do we need $\text{Greater}(y,z)$, and how does $\forall z$ shows there are an infinite number of pairs?

Comment: Suppose you remove the $z$, leaving you with just $\exists y ( \text{prime}(y) \wedge \text{prime}(\text{sum}(y, 2)))$. That would just say "there is a twin prime". The $\forall z$ (presumably your universe is $\mathbb{N}$) ensures that you have infinitely many different examples (thus representing the conjecture). It is only one way, there are many.

Comment: Also, images in questions are discouraged - [please use MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll edit it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula says that for any number $z$ you can find a prime pair $y, y+2$ that is even greater than that, i.e. there is no upper limit to prime pairs, and so there must be infinitely many.

This way of formalizing the existence of infinitely many elements only works because the natural numbers $z$ that are $\forall$ed are infinitely many.